Adding previous rows to generate another row in pandas
I am trying to solve a problem in my data-frame
df.head()
0    Key   value
1    10    500
2    11    500
3    12    600
4    12    800
5    13    1000
6    13    1200
. 
.
.
200++

output is to put the values in the above data-frame or have another data-frame with all the values of above with additional info show as below.
Expected Output:

0    Key   value
1    10    500
2    11    500
3    12    600
4    12    800
5    12    1400 -----> Addition of 800+600 as keys are same
6    13    1000 
7    13    1200
8    13    2200 -----> Addition of 1000+12000 as keys are same 
.
.
200++

I am just starting out in Pandas, any help will be appreciate.

This question is similar to: How can I use cumsum within a group in Pandas?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A possible solution, which takes the following steps:

First, groupby is used to organize df by Key, and then filter is applied with a lambda function that selects only groups with more than one row, ensuring sums are computed only for repeated Key values.

Next, this filtered group is re-aggregated with groupby to calculate the sum of value within each group of Key values using sum. The concatenated dataframe is then organized by Key and value columns through sort_values, with ignore_index=True to reset indexing.


(pd.concat([
    df, 
    df.groupby('Key').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
    .groupby('Key', as_index=False)['value'].sum()])
.sort_values('Key', ignore_index=True))


Another possible solution:
pd.concat(
    [df, 
     df.groupby('Key', as_index=False)['value']
     .apply(lambda x: None if len(x) == 1 else sum(x))
     .dropna()]).sort_values('Key', ignore_index=True)


Output:
   Key  value
0   10    500
1   11    500
2   12    600
3   12    800
4   12   1400
5   13   1000
6   13   1200
7   13   2200


Note that the first solution would incorrectly drop lines if they happen to have the same key/value (for instance if 800 was 600)

Thanks, @mozway! You are absolutely right, and I have meanwhile updated my first solution to fix that.

One option, keep the duplicated keys, aggregate with groupby.sum or groupby.first for the index, then concat and sort_index:
out = (pd.concat([df,
                  (df[df['Key'].duplicated(keep=False)]
                   .reset_index()
                   .groupby('Key', as_index=False)
                   .agg({'index': 'last', 'value': 'sum'})
                   .set_index('index')
                  ),]
                )
         .sort_index(kind='stable')
      )

NB. add ignore_index=True to sort_index to avoid the duplicated indices.
Output:
   Key  value
1   10    500
2   11    500
3   12    600
4   12    800
4   12   1400  # new row
5   13   1000
6   13   1200
6   13   2200  # new row

Variant to highlight the total rows:
out = (pd.concat([df,
                  (df[df['Key'].duplicated(keep=False)]
                   .reset_index()
                   .groupby('Key', as_index=False)
                   .agg({'index': 'last', 'value': 'sum'})
                   .set_index('index')
                   .assign(total='<-')
                  ),]
                )
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         .fillna({'total': ''})
      )

Output:
   Key  value total
0   10    500      
1   11    500      
2   12    600      
3   12    800      
4   12   1400    <-
5   13   1000      
6   13   1200      
7   13   2200    <-


thanks @mozway for an detailed reply.
